# Webpack (2) - 'Promise' is undefined when lazy load files

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to use Webpack (2) for async code splitting.

It works fine in browsers that support Promise by default but in IE11 (and less) I'm getting an error `'Promise' is undefined` for the Webpack's lazy-load function (`requireEnsure` or `__webpack_require__.e`) that uses a Promise to resolve the async `require`when the chunk's script has loaded.

I tried to use the `webpack.ProvidePlugin` with `Promise: 'es6-promise'` option and it looks like it's not polyfilled it, but anyway, I don't want to contaminate the global Promise in case the website already have that.

I tried to switch to Webpack 1 and it works fine because they implemented the lazy-load function with callbacks, but I prefer to use the newest Webpack.

It's quite weird that Webpack doesn't support IE11 so I assume there is some workaround for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

might be related to recent issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4916

Answer (score 0):

Webpack 2+ require `Promise` support for lazy loading, and since we don't/can't use a polyfill we used Webpack 1 and it works fine.